# Program run from eclipse is able to insert data into Mongo DB of local machine but not into Mongo DB of remote machine

Tags: java, eclipse, mongodb

Here is the code that I used:

```
package testing;
import com.mongodb.*;

public class MongoTest {

public static void main(String args[])
{
    try
    {
        MongoClient cli=new MongoClient("10.6.9.227",27017);
        DB dtbs=cli.getDB("test");
        System.out.println("Connection to DB successful");
        DBCollection col=dtbs.getCollection("newcol");
        BasicDBObject record=new    BasicDBObject("name","student1").append("sem","6");
        col.insert(record);
        System.out.println("Successfully Inserted into collection");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    { 
        System.out.println(e.getMessage()); 
    }
}}
```

This code inserts perfectly into the same machine from which this eclipse program is run(which is when 10.6.9.57 is specified while initializing cli object).

But, when I try to do the same thing in a remote machine in the same LAN (which is given by ip 10.6.9.227), this is what is displayed in eclipse console:

> Connection to DB successful
>   Timed out after 10000 ms while waiting for a server that matches AnyServerSelector{}. Client view of cluster state is {type=Unknown, servers=[{address=10.6.9.227:28017, type=Unknown, state=Connecting, exception={java.lang.NullPointerException}}]

The machine 10.6.9.57 runs on windows OS. I run my eclipse program from here. The remote machine 10.6.9.227 runs on Debian Squeeze OS.

I checked to see if the required ports are open through `netstat` command in the system 227:

```
 :~$ sudo netstat -lntup
    >Active Internet connections (only servers)
    >Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State                                                                                                  PID/Program name
    >tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN                                                                                                 848/portmap
   >tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:28017         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN                                                                                              2421/mongod
   >tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:49396           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN                                                                                              860/rpc.statd
   >tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN                                                                                              1566/sshd
   >tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5984          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN                                                                                              1163/beam.smp
   >tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN                                                                                              2421/mongod
   >tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN                                                                                              1566/sshd
   >udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:54866           0.0.0.0:*                                                                                                                   860/rpc.statd
   >udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:612             0.0.0.0:*                                                                                                                   860/rpc.statd
   >udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:32870           0.0.0.0:*                                                                                                                   1260/avahi-daemon:
   >udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                                                                                                                   1260/avahi-daemon:
   >udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*                                                                                                                   848/portmap
   >udp        0      0 10.6.9.227:123          0.0.0.0:*                                                                                                                   1610/ntpd
   >udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:123           0.0.0.0:*                                                                                                                   1610/ntpd
   >udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:123             0.0.0.0:*                                                                                                                   1610/ntpd
   >udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                                                                                                                        1260/avahi-daemon:
   >udp6       0      0 :::123                  :::*                                                                                                                        1610/ntpd
   >udp6       0      0 :::50061                :::*                                                                                                                          1260/avahi-daemon:
```

These ports are open only and I'm also able to insert in that local machine from it's own command line(through putty):

```
> db.newcol.insert({name:"firststudent"},{sem:"5"});
> db.newcol.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5571366e1031fc034ac63013"), "name" : "firststudent" }
```

Also, this is what the Mongo DB log file at /var/log/mongodb looks like:

```
Fri Jun  5 10:39:02 Mongo DB : starting : pid = 2421 port = 27017 dbpath = /var/lib/mongodb master = 0 slave = 0  64-bit
Fri Jun  5 10:39:02 db version v1.4.4, pdfile version 4.5
Fri Jun  5 10:39:02 git version: nogitversion
Fri Jun  5 10:39:02 sys info: Linux bobek-a0 2.6.32-trunk-amd64 #1 SMP Sun Jan 10 22:40:40 UTC 2010 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_42
Fri Jun  5 10:39:02 waiting for connections on port 27017
Fri Jun  5 10:39:02 web admin interface listening on port 28017
```

I am just not able to resolve why a java program run from eclipse of a machine connected to the same LAN is not able to do it. I have included the mongo-java-driver-2.13.0-rc1.jar. I have even tried stopping and restarting the mongo db in the remote machine and repeated this process several times. But still not able to insert. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

- `telnet` from your box to the remote mongo box to the port `27017`.
  See if you can.
- connect to remote mongo from your local mongo client (not java/eclipse) see if that succeeds. Not from it's own localhost but from your machine to remote via mongo client
- Check mongo config on the remote machine (especially check `/etc/mongod.conf`, and the value for the bind_ip setting.

Comment: I actually tried un-installing the old version and installed a newer version of mongo DB. Now it's working. Thanks for your help :)